# Installing and Re-installing XAMPP

Tags: xampp

I have recently installed XAMPP on my computer it was working fine but my friend accidentally deleted the XAMPP folder.So when I reinstallled it isn't working,ports for Apache and MySql are showing that they are busy.

What should I do ?

Comment: Give us more details...operating system ? distribution (if linux)...

Answer (score 0):

If you are running Skype, then you can easily change its ports. `Go to Tools -> Advanced -> Connections` and uncheck the `Use Port 80` and `443` option and close Skype. Now again try to start Apache. You should be able to do it.

Comment: When I re install it Apache is working but MySql is isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Have a look there "[How to get open ports](http://www.petri.co.il/quickly_find_local_open_ports.htm)" it explains how to see what ports are open and which programs opened them.

Answer (score 0):

Start running `mysqld.exe` file which will be seen in the `bin` folder inside your MySQL installation.